# CSS form not applying

Tags: css

I have this form:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-6" align="center">        
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email"> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

And I am trying to apply this CSS to it:

```
input [type="text"], input [type="password"] {
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin:20px auto;
}
```

But it is not applying. I have my css linked up to the page too.

Comment: Well no the form works and it displays but the CSS doesn't change it

Answer (score 3):

Remove the spacing so it would be input[....]

```css
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  margin:20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-6" align="center">        
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email"> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="and password" name="password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `input [type="text"], input [type="password"] {`

That would select elements *inside* an input element (impossible in HTML) that have a type of text or password - you need to remove the spaces, to select input elements that *themsleves* are of type text or password:

`input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {`